# Selenium Extraction…Need to extract text of element located by CSS Selector

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a very frustrating time trying to figure out what is going on. My code was working last week, but for whatever reason I am not getting any results any more. I am getting a timeout message when searching for the css selector "h3.one" on the website. My code is supposed to find all elements with that css selector and of those elements, return the one that is diplayed.

**I need help especially with the implicit wait**

Here is my code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.voilanorbert.com/')
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-name")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][0])
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][1])
searchbutton = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
searchbutton.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
h3s = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
result = h3.text
print (result)
```

The print is only for the purpose to see what is being extracted/make sure that it is actually doing what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an another `h3` element with `class="one"` which is really invisible. This element is messing things up.

Either make your selector specific to the "success" container (works for me):

```
div#result-success h3.one
```

or wait for the `results` block to appear:

```
div.results
```

Comment: If its invisible, why would it mess things up? Doesn't the code above just look for a visible  h3 element with class="one"?

Comment: I can't make the selector specific to the "success" container, because the result is not always "success"...you see it could be "result-error h3.one", "result-fail h3.one", "result-catchall h3.one", or "result-success h3.one"

Comment: you have to be very very specific with selenium.  no ambiguity! `:)`

Comment: @ohbrobig looks like you did something wrong. You should just replace `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))` with `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results")))`.

Comment: Its working now. How do I get this to work with Chrome? I get a "StopIteration" error that is only specific to chrome...

Comment: @ohbrobig great! Let's make this a separate issue please. Consider creating a separate question.

Comment: Check that out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354709/selenium-program-works-fine-for-firefox-but-not-chrome