# Selenium...Program Works Fine for Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code below works fine with Firefox, but when I set browser=webdriver.Chrome() I get some issues.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.voilanorbert.com/')
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-name")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][0])
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][1])
searchbutton = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
searchbutton.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results")))
h3s = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
result = h3.text
```

With chrome, everything is fine up until I need to extract text. I get this error:

```
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
StopIteration
```

**EDIT**
Problem showing up again on both firefox and chrome. I even added a fluent wait.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results")))
wait2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 3000, poll_frequency=100, ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException])
wait2.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
h3s = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
result = h3.text
```

I have came to the conclusion that selenium is definitely not perfect.

Comment: How is `h3s` defined?

Comment: Edited to show. Just forgot to post that line.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key problem here is in the **animation** happening when the results are shown.

You need to let `selenium` know that you want it to *wait before searching for an element* via [`implicitly_wait()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.implicitly_wait):

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results")))

# okay, selenium, slow down, please
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
h3s = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
```

(worked for me)

Comment: That worked too...(once I changed the wait time to a little bit longer, 10 secs)

Comment: So its not working with chrome or firefox. I am getting the same error even after adding a fluent wait:

Answer (score 1):

If it is a wait issue I've had good experience with fluent wait:

https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html